# Send Email Is Not Working In Site Page

Tags: force.com-sites

We have one site page which send the Email to the Contact (Custom field in Opportunity record.) and we set the Opportunity Id as What ID.
The Activity History get created but, Contact Email address does not receive any Email.

Comment: More information is required here, any relevant code you can show? VF page, Apex?

Comment: We have resolved this issue. Actually the User from which emails are sent have email address domain is not working. We have trace it through the email log.

Comment: The please add as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

We have traced the issue and resolved it, Actually from address domain is not working.